# HTML 5 support in Firefox 4

Tags: javascript, firefox, html

Does Firefox fully support HTML5 APIs? I have seen in some other questions (I cannot remember where) that `BlobBuilder` is not supported in Firefox.

In addition, when I try to use `BlobBuilder` object in JavaScript,  I am getting an error says "`BlobBuilder` is not defined". I am using Firefox 4.0b7 version for HTML5 based development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that [searching MDC for `BlobBuilder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=Blobbuilder) turned up no results, and that on the latest daily build (Firefox 4b13), running `BlobBuilder` resulted in a reference error, I believe that this API will not be implemented in Firefox 4 when it comes out of beta (which will be very soon, [given that no blockers remain](http://canweshipyet.com/))

Answer (score 0):

http://www.caniuse.com/#cats=HTML5,JS_API

Looks like recent versions of FireFox support almost everything in HTML5 (including API's)